# How to change the collection on the basis of array in column value

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-5

I want to change the laravel collection because I want to pass this collection to generate report.
How to change collection on the basis of the value in the column.

Previous:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 23
[form_type] => radio
[details] => [{"id":55 title:"AA" name:"BB"}, {"id":56 title:"CC" name:"DD"}]
)
[1] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 24
[form_type] => checkbox
[details] => [{"id":57 title:"PP" name:"QQ"}, {"id":58 title:"RR" name:"SS"}]
)
)
)
```

--details column has array of objects, I want it as below format:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 23
[form_type] => radio
[title] => "AA"
[name] =>  "BB"     
)
[1] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 23
[form_type] => radio
[title] => "CC"
[name] =>  "DD"     
)        
[2] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 24
[form_type] => checkbox
[title] => "PP"
[name] =>  "QQ"
)
[4] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 24
[form_type] => checkbox
[title] => "RR"
[name] =>  "SS"
)
)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to use each method of Laravel collection. I expect the data in the following format and you will get the desired output.

```
$data = collect([
    (object)["id" => 23, "form_type" => "radio", "details" => [["id" => 55, 'title' => "AA", 'name' => "BB"], ["id" => 56, 'title' => "CC", 'name' => "DD"]]]
]);
$result = collect();
$data->each(function($d) use ($result) {
    $d = collect($d);
    unset($t['id']);
    $tmp = collect($d['details']);
    $tmp->each(function($t) use (&$d, $result) {
        $result->push($d->forget('details')->merge($t));
    });
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this with `->map()` function then `->push()` into new collection

```php
$data = [
    [
        "id" => 23,
        "form_type" => "radio",
        "details" => [["id" => 55, "title" => "AA", "name" => "BB"], ["id" => 56, "title" => "CC", "name" => "DD"]]
    ],
    [
        "id" => 24,
        "form_type" => "checkbox",
        "details" => [["id" => 57, "title" => "PP", "name" => "QQ"], ["id" => 58, "title" => "RR", "name" => "SS"]]
    ],
];

$data = collect($data);

$final = collect();
$data->map(function ($row) use ($data, $final) {
    return collect($row['details'])->map(function ($item) use ($data, $row, $final) {
        $parentData = $data->where('id', $row['id'])->first();
        $final->push([
            'id' => $parentData['id'],
            'title' => $item['title'],
            'form_type' => $parentData['form_type'],
            'name' => $item['name']
        ]);
    });
});
return $final;
```